# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have project in .NET core MVC and my visual studio 2022 version was `17.5.1` after update visual studio 2022 version to `17.7.5`.

The first error message after update was:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Show' was not found. The
> following locations were searched: /Views/Account/Show.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Show.cshtml
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable
> originalLocations)

I solved this error by

1. add this package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`
2. then change `services.AddControllersWithViews()` to `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`

and it works fine but after publishing to IIS the website not working

I expected AddRazorRuntimeCompilation not woking fine in IIS

Comment: Have you had a look at the server and application logs?

Comment: yes i look and i see this error

Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
EventId: 2
SpanId: c6153d9b71687d52
TraceId: 9f79dfae01aef1b379474aa65fd76d1f
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000094-0006-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /hr

Connection ID "18374686507052040339", Request ID "80000094-0006-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Comment: i see this error from 
Event Viewer -windows logs - application 

because the browser dose't display any thing

Comment: The error is still the view show not found?

Comment: yes you right this issue appear after update

Comment: Could you please tell me how you host your asp.net core application inside the IIS? Directly add as web application or add as a nested web application?

Comment: thanks  a lot Brado to help me 
I host my web site inside sites > default web sites > hr

Comment: How about you put this website not inside the default web sites and create a new web application in IIS. \

Comment: yes i put my host in sites>Hr
but the same issue

Comment: Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
EventId: 2
SpanId: d959725691f91508
TraceId: 60bfc3f06e266a6179a6c63d5a2828cb
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 800000c7-0006-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /

Connection ID "18158513724938256581", Request ID "800000c7-0006-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Comment: Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Show' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Account/Show.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Show.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Show.cshtml
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.

Comment: So you don't have the view or you have specific settings for your asp.net core application?

Comment: No i have the views but the issue happen after upgrade 17.5.1 to 17.7.5